# How to invert arrow image placed before the first cell when tableview cells are swiped beyond first cell?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my application, I need to add this functionality that there should be an arrow image upside down placed before first cell and some text like "Pull down to refresh" and when user pulls the table beyond this then this arrow gets inverted and text changes to "Release to refresh" and when the user releases his finger, the data is refreshed and rows get added to that point So now this initial arrow and text moves upwards before the first cell again.

Can anybody tell me wheather there's any event that does this? Or else which event I need to capture in order to add this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything (and I mean everything) you want is here
[Pull to reload tableview](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2009/12/how-to-make-a-pull-to-reload-tableview-just-like-tweetie-2/)

Comment: Thought you might be :-) (I've not tried it myself yet, but just have it stored for when I need it!)